# Git push stick with no error message on git version 2.33.1 on macOS Monterey 12.0.1

Tags: git, git-push, macos-monterey

My current local `development` branch is ahead of my remote branch by 2 commits.

When I `git push` I get the following terminal output:

```
Enumerating objects: 24, done.
Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 7.17 MiB | 2.86 MiB/s, done.
Total 22 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

With no return back to my shell. It's not clear to me what I've done wrong with no error message. I only added 10 images to my repo that were very small `.png` files.

I've been using `git` for 7 years & have never had this problem so I'm confused as to what is happening. I have `git version 2.33.1` on macOS `Monterey version 12.0.1`

Comment: At this point in `git push`, *your* Git has finished all the work it needs to do. It is now waiting for the other side of this conversation—the Git to which you're pushing—to acknowledge receipt of everything and tell you whether they accepted your update requests. So there seems to be nothing wrong on *your* end: it's the other (remote) Git that's not responding.

Comment: I see, so your hypothesizing it's just a bad internet connection or my remote git server is down?

Comment: Maybe. It's not clear what's gone wrong, but if you haven't replaced anything (software or hardware) on "your side" of the Internet wiring, it's very probably something on "their side".